# C# Class Changed Event causing Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, events

I need an event to fire when I change a property.  When I run this code I get a Object reference not set to an instance of an object.  What am I doing wrong?  What is the correct way to instantiate an event, and fire it when a property is set?

public member:

```
public event System.EventHandler ClassChanged;
```

property set:

```
ClassChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to verify the event handler it not null first:

```
if (ClassChanged != null)
    ClassChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
```

But in general, you may want to wrap this up into a helper method like so:

```
private void NotifyClassChanged() {
    if (ClassChanged != null)
        ClassChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

Or possibly implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) instead.

Comment: +1 (if I had votes left today) for the INotifyPropertyChanged bit. Your psychic debugging took it to the next level!

Comment: I agree - INotifyPropertyChanged sounds like the appropriate option here.  That being said, I prefer making a copy of the invocation list prior to the null check (for thread safety) - even if it's single threaded, it's a good habit to have.

Comment: ClassChanged isn't null, I still get the same exception thrown

Comment: @Kevin - Chances are the problem is else where then. Doesn't Visual Studio show you where the exception occurs?

Comment: @Kevin: can we get the stack trace? Perhaps the handler itself has a `NullReferenceException`.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
System.EventHandler handler = this.ClassChanged;
if (handler != null)
{
    handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's doing that because no eventhandlers have been subscribed to the event.

The proper way to make sure the event's multicast delegate is not `null` that is thread-safe:

```
var cc = ClassChanged; //makes a copy
if (cc != null)
    cc(this, EventArgs.Empty);
```

However, the method I prefer is to declare the event with an empty lambda handler so it is never `null`:

```
public event EventHandler ClassChanged = (o,e) => {};
```

Comment: As you've declared it `public`, what is to stop someone setting: `ClassChanged = null`? It's probably better to add null checking in for race conditions, just to be on the safe side.

Comment: @Matthew: Outside of the class, you can only add handlers with `+=` and remove handlers with `-=`. The `event` declaration is syntax sugar for a property with `AddHandler` and `RemoveHandler` (instead of `get` and `set`) with a backing delegate.

Answer (score 1):

Like joel said there are no listeters attached to this method which is why your getting an exception. Another way to handle this would be to create a method, which checks to see if its null and then call this method instead of the Event

So if you have

```
public event System.EventHandler ClassChanged;    

ClassChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
```

You create the following method

```
private void OnClassChanged()
{
   if (ClassChanged != null)
   {
       ClassChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
   }
}
```

and call OnClassChanged(...) and not the ClassChanged(...) event

Answer (score 0):

It could be that there is no eventhandler attached to ClassChanged. (Cannot see the rest of the code)
Therefore check first if ClassChanged is not null before firing it.

```
if (ClassChanged != null)
{
  ClassChanged(this, nully);

}
```